# Eckmann-Hilton argument

Tags: higher-category-theory

The Eckmann-Hilton argument is used to prove that a doubly monoidal 0-category is a commutative monoid. If (x) is horizontal composition and . is vertical composition, and assuming that 1(x)a=a=a(x)1, then

a(x)b=(1.a)(x)(b.1)=(1(x)b).(a(x)1)=b.a=(b(x)1).(1(x)a)=(b.1)(x)(1.a)=b(x)a

which shows first that the two kinds of multiplications are the same and second that they are commutative. In a weak 2-category, horizontal composition of 2-cells is only unital up to conjugation by some invertible 2-cells (the unitors). My question is how does one prove the assumption, that horizontal composition is strictly unital, in this situation?

Comment: You can use html symbols here (http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html). For example, you can type &otimes; to get ⊗.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in fact *three* binary operations in play here.  There are vertical composition . and horizontal composition * (or "(x)"), as you say.  But then there's also the operation @, as follows.

Your "*a*" and "*b*" here are 2-cells of a doubly degenerate weak 2-category.  Let's call its unique 0-cell *x*; then *a* and *b* are 2-cells from 1<sub>*x*</sub> to 1<sub>*x*</sub>.  Part of the structure of the weak 2-category is a coherence isomorphism lambda: 1<sub>*x*</sub> o 1<sub>*x*</sub> --> 1<sub>*x*</sub>.  So, given *a* and *b*, we can form the vertical composite

*a* @ *b* = (lambda . (*a* * *b*) . lambda^{-1}).

Now, 1<sub>1<sub>*x*</sub></sub> is a unit for both . and @, and they satisfy the interchange law, so the Eckmann-Hilton argument applies to tell you that . and @ are equal and commutative.  It follows that * = @. It *then* follows that horizontal composition * is strictly unital, as required.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But I need 1_{1_x} to be both a left and right unit for @. If I choose lambda to be the left unitor coherence isomorphism then 1_{1_x} is a left unit for @, but is it obviously a right unit?